When we can use kendall tau correlation?
I am seeing in my field that some are using Kendall's tau rank correlation and some are using  Spearman's rank correlation. Can you please explain the main difference and when to use Spearman and when is preferred to use Kendall?

They both measure  the strength of monotonic relationship but they "see" different aspects of bivariate dependence (the population Spearman and Kendall correlations are different functions of the population copula). What Kendall is doing is somewhat easier to describe in simple terms (difference between probability of concordance and discordance). There are some other posts besides the linked duplicate that you might get some value from so a search or two may be helpful.
